# Anybody using a laptop with an SSD as the main drive?

Tags: computer, storage, portable-recording

I'm thinking about swapping out my MBP 13" hard drive for a 128 GB SSD, in the hope that it will be more battery efficient.

Do any of you have experience with these drives?

How is the battery life?
Does read/write speed deteriorate with time?

Cheers,

Kurt

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment personally, but from what I've read, you'll notice extremely fast boot times for the system and applications. Read/Write speed does currently deteriorate with time due to the lack of TRIM support:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM

But OSX 10.7 will add this. Formatting the drive would restore its read/write times but of course, if you're using it as an OS drive, that's hardly a solution.

If you search around the Avid DUC, I' sure someone had PT running on one of the newer Macbook Airs, and those have static drives for their system, so that might give you an idea of the performance increase.

Hope this helps!
Joe

Answer (score 1):

I put the hybrid disk mentioned by C3Sound in my 2007 MBP. It's a Seagate Momentus XT 500 GB with 4 GB flash. It runs all right and is quite a bit faster than the stock drive, but it's not the holy grail that the manufacturer wants you to believe it is:

- You have no control over what goes on the solid state part, that's automatic (the files that are used the most go on the 4 GB part).
- There are some problems with the drive spinning down at the wrong time, and then immediately spinning back up. This causes the interface of my DAW to freeze for a few seconds, though audio continues without interruptions. This is supposed to be fixed with a firmware update, but I haven't tested that yet because the update tool is windows only.
- It's not nearly as fast as a proper SSD, say a Crucial or Corsair Vertex or Intel drive.
- It actually uses more power, generates more heat and makes more noise compared to the stock drive, because the stock one runs at 5400 rpm and this one at 7200.

So it's a compromise between storage space and speed for a low price. If you want speed and battery efficiency, I'd suggest a proper ssd, with an external 2.5" 5400 rpm hard drive for storage.

Comment: eesh - removing my post! thanks for the info!

Comment: Thanks for the information,
No I am definitely going for a full SSD, as a need a bit of a dual purpose machine. I spend a lot of time going out to meetings on the train and would like to be able do a bit of editing/organising while travelling and to take my projects with me to clients to help our discussions along.

I also do live sound design for theatre and it seems like the perfect option (hard drive speed wise).

Comment: @C3Sound WOW! That full SSD you mentioned for $1,700 - lol! Personally, I'd rather buy a Schoeps CMIT5U and wait for the SSDs to come down in price. I bet you $1,700 that the price of that drive comes down to $99 in about 2 years :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 500g sssd in my mbp. Running nuendo with no issues. Its super fast and works fine.

Comment: Do you mind telling us what brand and model pweez?

Comment: Not sure. Whatever one apple puts in the current mbp models. 